# Copying the data from a small data.frame to a bigger data.frame

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

Let `d` be a pre-allocated big matrix

```
d = as.data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=3,nrow=5e7))
names(d) = c("x","y","z")
```

`dsub` is a small matrix with the same number of columns and same column names as `d`

```
dsub = data.frame(x = 1:4,y=1:4,z=1:4)
```

I wish to copy data from `dsub` into `d` at lines 5 to 8

```
d[5:8,] = dsub
```

This operation is very slow. It seems that `R` is copying the entire data.frame `d`!

- Why is it so?
- How can one make this process faster?

Comment: Yes ... Virginia ... R is copying the entire dataframe. That's how R works. It's maybe even worse than you think. It may be copying it more than once. The `data.table` package was built to get around that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288411/copying-the-data-from-a-small-data-frame-to-a-bigger-data-frame#comment73646021_43288411) the `data.table` package was mentioned to overcome the problem with copying the whole object when modifying only a few rows.

The best way to demonstrate the effect is a benchmark. Thereby, the different approaches the `data.table` package offers can be compared.

## Setting up data

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA_integer_, ncol = 3, nrow = 5e7))
names(df) = c("x", "y", "z")
dt <- setDT(copy(df))
dsub <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1:4, z = 1:4)
```

Note that the target object is initialized with `NA_integer_` instead of `NA` which is of type `logical`. This avoids the overhead which is caused by coercing the left hand side to integer (and the repective warnings issued by `data.table`).

## Benchmarking

```
mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  df = d[5:8,] <- dsub,
  dt1 = dt[5:8] <- dsub,
  dt2 = dt[5:8, (c("x","y","z")) := .SD],
  dt3 = set(dt, 5:8, 1:3, dsub),
  times = 10,
  unit = "ms"
)

print(mb, unit = "relative")
#Unit: relative
# expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
#   df 56458.1921 27397.98069 27932.40685 29796.52860 34413.21160 29487.64751    10   b
#  dt1 49142.9608 24959.42180 22909.58526 20687.62826 30129.96416 21349.51295    10   b
#  dt2   111.9582    86.57717    54.36988    70.89935    69.36287    31.89704    10  a 
#  dt3     1.0000     1.00000     1.00000     1.00000     1.00000     1.00000    10  a
```

Note that the benchmark results are printed relative to the fastest method which is `data.table`'s `set()` function. However, updating by reference using regular `data.table` systax (case `dt2`) is magnitudes faster than the `data.frame` way.